# bad alloc c++ loading file in matrix

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

I try to load a large file (20gb) and load it into a matrix. However I get a bad_alloc error when it tries to load the file in the matrix. My code is working on Mac but doesn't on Linux.

Here is my code:

```
std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ifstream::binary);

loadModel(ifs);

void loadModel(std::istream& in) {
     input_ = std::make_shared<Matrix>();
     input_->load(in); // bad_alloc
}
```

Comment: How much RAM / virtual memory do you have available on each box?

Comment: Mac: 16gb and Linux 8gb.

Comment: You'd normally use memory mapped files when you have more data than memory

Comment: Running your application under `gdb` set a breakpoint on the line `input_->load(in)`.  When execution stops there do [`catch throw`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html#Set-Catchpoints) and continue.  `gdb` should then stop the next time an exception is thrown.  At that point you can examine the stack/variables etc.

Comment: Sorry, but that's clearly off-topic: You must extract and provide a [mcve], but your code is far away from that. Pay attention to the dependency on the data file as well. In any case, the meaning of `bad_alloc` is documented, so you might want to work on your question as well.

Comment: I can't use gdb because I have a strange error: "at src/a_file.cpp:10311
10311 src/a_file.cpp: No such file or directory."

Comment: Those errors are because the source files in question have been compiled without [debugging information](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Compilation.html#Compilation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bad alloc` means an error during memory allocation. Probably your matrix does not fit into operating memory available.

You can check available memory with `free` command

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       32780268     2055964    29109172      193300     1615132    30106808
Swap:        999420           0      999420
```

In this output, it tells that 29GB available.

Comment: I have 7GB available, does it mean my server can't hold more than 7gb variable ?

Comment: Yes. 7GB means that you can only have 7GB of data loaded. That's what "gigabyte" means. If you have a ten pound sack of potatoes, you can't get more than ten pounds of potatoes inside it. Same general principle.

Comment: Okay, but isn't the computer supposed to create virtual memory? When I monitor the memory of my Mac during the process, the ram consumption of the program actually goes way higher than my 16gb of physical memory. What about Linux?

Comment: A computer does not "create virtual memory". You are confusing virtual memory with swap space. Your Mac is probably configured with some amount, possibly dynamic amount, of swap space. A Linux system can also be configured with swap space. See the `Swap` line, above. However the only one who would know whether your Linux system has any amount of swappable RAM would be you. Nobody else here could possibly know that.

Comment: The general advice here, do not load the whole 20GB into RAM. Create another approach that will load smaller data chunks and process them.

Comment: I created more swap space in my linux: was 2gb and I set it to 20gb. My program now runs but it is very slow (logically).  :'(  I don't know how to load smaller data chunks of a pre-trained machine elarning model. It would a be huge work to make it works.

Comment: Is there a way to cache the variable allocation or something? In order to not wait 3min for the program to launch every time....

Comment: The fastest fix would be to just buy more RAM.